# New SSH Connection failed Google Cloud VM

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04, google-compute-engine

I recently formatted my system, I thought better to create new SSH for login into the system from the Local system.

**Steps I followed** :

1. Remove all previous keys to VM leaving one Key, which is user_name.
2. Tried connecting to **In Browser SSH** it started failing, I tried rebooting VM Nothing works. 
   3.Then copied previously all SSH keys from backups into my local system just to make connection and working side by not affecting my development.
   4.Added new SSH Keys in VM Instance Project Wide SSH keys, tried logging into VM Instance from the local system, **Successfully**.
3. Tried with google-cloud SDK using previous key Successful.
4. But Browser SSH is still failing.
5. ~/ssh/authroized_keys there are keys which I added for automatic deployment.

**Problems which I detected** : 
  1. After the following [troubleshooting from google](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting), when I tried login using fresh user it's failed.

```
gcloud compute ssh test@vh-server
Updating project ssh metadata.../Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name].
Updating project ssh metadata...done.                                                    
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
Permission denied (public key).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not SSH into the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again.  If you still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.
```

2. New SSH login using new public and a private key is also failing. I created new keys, updated SSH keys in VM instance.

   ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key test@ip_address
   ssh: connect to host ip_address port 22: Operation timed out
3. No In Browser SSH Login.

I followed this question no help [Not able to browser login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046736/unable-to-connect-to-google-compute-engine-using-in-browser-ssh)

Any Help would be appreciated

**Problem** : -

I am not able to do in browser SSH Connection

Comment: You can ssh to the instance using your existing keys and make sure GCE daemon scripts are running on the VM, specially Accounts script. This script is responsible to sync user account and ssh keys from metadata server to the instance.

Comment: This cloud be an issue related to old GCE daemons installed on your VM. You can follow the steps on [this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages#package-distribution) to update the repositories on your VM and than update the GCE packages.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If so please consider posting an answer, it would benefit the community. As per Faizan comment this could be related to new key format not being accepted by old guest enviroments as described [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/67997017)

Comment: @Faizan Yes Accounts Script is working 
`OK  [0m] Started LSB: MD monitoring daemon.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Accounts Service.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Login to default iSCSI targets.
`
Steps you asked me to follow It's throws me error source list `tee`. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and python 2.7. I no expert in this

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this resolved my problem: I am able to log in from the browser and new keys

If you're seeing this on Debian 8 or 9, the most likely reason for this is that the google-compute-engine.* packages that allow SSH access to the instance has been removed by `apt-get autoremove`.

If you have an open SSH connection to the machine or can use a tool like `gcloud`, running `apt-get update` && `sudo apt-get install gce-compute-image-packages` should fix this.

If you no longer have any SSH access, there is a procedure available on the GCP docs site that can be used to restore it.

For more : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48257469/637377.